# How can I ORDER BY a column Text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm trying to `ORDER BY` a column in SQL Server which is a `TEXT` type. How can I do that? I couldn't find in the internet..

Answer (score 2):

You can't. TEXT is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). use [VARCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)(MAX)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(50) ,ColumnName)
```